# Transitive Closure in Z3/Z3py

Tags: z3, z3py

Context: I'm using the Programming Z3 guide:
https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html

It looks like Z3 now has built-in support for transitive-closure, but for the moment it's only accessible via Z3py:
https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-transitive-closure

I have two questions:

(1) Is there any means of accessing TransitiveClosure via other APIs or the executable directly via "z3 -in", or is it just for Z3py at the moment?

(2) Is TransitiveClosure supposed to interoperate with push and pop? We built from the master branch earlier this week (commit 2788f72bbb6bfd6bdad2da2b4c37ef1bb502469d) and ran the following example:

```
from z3 import *
B = BoolSort()
S = DeclareSort('S')
a, b, c = Consts('a b c', S)
R = Function('R', S, S, B)
TCR = TransitiveClosure(R)
s = Solver()

s.add(R(a, b) == True)
s.push()     # If this line is uncommented (or both are) the result is sat, which is wrong.
s.add(TCR(a, b) == False)
s.push()     # But if THIS line is uncommented (or neither are), the result is unsat, which is correct.

print(s)
print(s.check())
```

As the comments indicate, a push() call between assertions about R and its transitive closure seem to break the link between the two relations. Not sure if this is a bug, or my own misunderstanding...

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of it, it's also available via the C/C++ api as well:

https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/62de187d02d8d2e7a3667a31753c508f7c73aaa1/src/api/c%2B%2B/z3%2B%2B.h#L637-L639

I don't think it's available from the SMTLib interface (what you meant by `z3 -in` I presume), as it's itself returning a relation; and such higher-order constructs are usually not allowed in SMTLib. (But there might be a "magic" switch, of course; z3 is known to experiment with functionality that's not part of SMTLib.)

Regarding whether it should work with push/pop: I don't think the fixed-point engine in z3 allows for incremental solving; so I'm not surprised that it's behaving erratically. You should definitely report this behaviour at their issues site (https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues) so they can at least issue an error message if you try to do incremental stuff, instead of spitting out misleading info. (Or maybe you hit a bug! So, that'd also be good for them to know.)

Answer (score 1):

s.pop(),s.push() is not necessary.

```
# https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-transitive-closure
from z3 import *
B = BoolSort()
S = DeclareSort('S')

R = Function('R', S, S, B)
TCR = TransitiveClosure(R)
a, b, c = Consts('a b c', S)
s = Solver()

s.add(R(a, b))
s.add(R(b, c))
s.add(Not(TCR(a, c))) # s.add(Not(R(a, c))) will be “sat”,because TCR is transitiveclosure but R is not.
print(s)
print(s.check())  # unsat
```